# Can't multi select check boxs for RadDataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagridview

I can select one check box, but when i go to click another checkbox the previous one gets removed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding CheckAll}">
             <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn.GroupHeaderTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Checked="CheckAll_Checked" Unchecked="CheckAll_Checked" />
    </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Date" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Loan Account" DataMemberBinding="{Binding AccountNumber}" />  
     </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 </telerik:RadGridView >
```

Checked code, I hope this is what you are referring to:

```
private void CheckAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid.Items.OfType<CashFlowDTO>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Post = CheckAll);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the Checked event handler? I suspect that this may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Added Checked code I believe.

Comment: If there's other you need please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the line of code in CheckAll_Checked? That would be a quick way to find out if it is causing the problem.